# Odoo: reference another record by its name in qweb

Tags: report, odoo, qweb

This is probably really simple, but I'm really tired. Anyway, I am writing custom invoice reports and I need to reference fields that are on the sale order that generated the invoice. This would be easy if they had a relational field, but they don't and I'm not allowed to put one in. The invoice when generated from a sale order has an 'origin' field where it stores the 'name' field of the sale order. I need to reference fields from said sale order via this field. Something along the lines of 
 `sale.order.browse('name', '=', o.origin).incoterm` <- if incoterm was the field I needed. 
So anyone can help me with the proper syntax? Or maybe I have the wrong idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in this manner,

```
sale_order = self.pool.get('sale.order')
order_id = sale_order.search(cr,uid,[('name','=',o.orgin)])
if order_id:
    sale_obj = sale_order.browse(cr,uid,order_id[0])
```

then you can use sale_obj with dot notation to access corresponding sale order field value. eg: sale_obj.incoterm